# Error al instalar native-base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

Al intentar instalar **native-base** con `npm install native-base` me aparece lo siguiente:

***ERROR:***

```
npm install native-base 
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mypassage@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from native-base@3.4.20
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"*" from native-base@3.4.20
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\jmoreno\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jmoreno\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-01T17_14_13_177Z-debug-0.log
```

A que se debe.

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "mypassage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: En SO en inglés hay [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526849/2412893) que podría servirte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionar o **overrides** para a biblioteca que será instalada utilizar a versão do react que está em seu projeto (a mesma versão que está dentro do objeto dependencies.react ("react": "18.0.0")).

```
{
  "name": "mypassage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react": "18.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: You're at SO en español, so please answer in spanish}

Comment: Gracias @Matheus Eduardo, tu respuesta soluciono mi problema :)